# Kendo combobox multiple set of data for different comboboxes

Tags: javascript, mvvm, combobox, kendo-ui

I am trying to setup a page that is using Javascript MVVM and kendo's combobox. I followed the tutorial on their site..

I have multiple comboboxes on the same page. Right now, if you toggle a combobox and select a value, it changes it for all of them. How would I set things up so that each combobox pulls from the same data, but is mutually exclusive?

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    config: [
        { name: "Service Config", value: "config1" },
        { name: "Service Config2", value: "config2" },
        { name: "Service Config3", value: "config3" }
    ]
    comboBoxValue: null,
    displayComboBoxValue: function() {
        var comboBoxValue = this.get("comboBoxValue");
        return kendo.stringify(comboBoxValue);
    }
});

viewModel.comboBoxValue = viewModel.config[0];

kendo.bind($(".services"), viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<select data-role="combobox"
        data-text-field="name"
        data-value-field="value"
        data-bind="source: config, value: comboBoxValue">
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using kendo DataSource and filters ?

While initializing your comboboxes you can populate them with a filtered datasource (originally looks up to the same data which was your intend).

Here you can find a dojo I've created to demonstrate this answer.
http://dojo.telerik.com/ECIgA